# what is the difference in ways setting indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the difference between how I set index of the data frame?

```
data = [['A', 5], ['B', 6], ['C', 7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['key', 'amount'], index= ['key'])
```

I get following error:

```
Shape of passed values is (2, 3), indices imply (2, 1)
```

If I do following ways it's working ok:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['key', 'amount'])
df2.set_index(['key'], inplace=True)
```

What is the difference between the ways I set the indexes ?

Comment: You can't specify a column for the index, it's expecting an index object or array-like with the same length as the final df, so you'd have to do this as a post construction step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first way:

```
data = [['A', 5], ['B', 6], ['C', 7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['key', 'amount'], index= ['key'])
```

You are specifying the index to be a single value of `'key'`.  Said another way, there will be a single row whose label is `'key'`.

In the second way:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['key', 'amount'])
df2.set_index(['key'], inplace=True)
```

You've specified a column named `'key'` that may contain many rows.  You subsequently instruct `df2` to make it's index equal to the entire column named `'key'`.

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand, [`pd.Dataframe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) expects index to be an array, and will be used as index for the rows, for example :

```
In [17]: data
Out[17]: [['A', 5], ['B', 6], ['C', 7]]

In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
   0  1
a  A  5
b  B  6
c  C  7
```

This is not what you are trying to achieve.

On the other hand [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index) sets one (or more) column(s) to **become** the index, which is what you want to do in this case.